# Reference to an instance method of a particular object breaks the type-safety in Java?

Tags: java-8, type-safety, method-reference

Does the notion of a reference to an instance method of a particular object break the type-safety in Java?

According to

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

you can have a custom class ComparisonProvider  that DOES not implement the Comparator  interface, and still use an instance of this class as the second argument of the method

Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator c)

Sure, the implementation of your ComparisonProvider MUST have a method whose signature exactly matches the Comparator.compare() method, but that is still not an instance of Comparator, isn't it?

In essence, Java 8 allows us to use instances of classes as if they were implementing a particular interface, while actually they are not.

This means, that we are loosing Type-safety in Java, do we?

Comment: You should write an [MCVE] that shows what you're asking. A method reference is not the same as an instance of the class that defines the method.

Comment: @pvg, thanks, you are right of course, I will try to be more precise in the future

Comment: If you mean method references, no, you don't end up losing typesafety because the method reference still has to match the type of the method defined by the functional interface and this remains enforced at compile time. You don't end up with the ability to pass whatever you want as the second parameter to `Arrays.sort`, for instance.

Answer (score 4):

lambda expressions and method reference don't have a predefined type, they are *poly expressions*, as seen [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html). That means that their type is derived from the context in which they are used.

In your example these both would be legal for example:

```
 BiFunction<Person, Person, Integer> biFun = myComparisonProvider::compareByName;

 Comparator<Person> comp = myComparisonProvider::compareByName;
```

But at the same time you can't do:

```
Arrays.sort(pers, biFun);
```

When you actually try to sort the array like this:

```
Arrays.sort(pers, myComparisonProvider::compareByName);
```

At the bytecode level that *is* a `Comparator`:

```
// InvokeDynamic #0:compare:(LTest$ComparisonProvider;)Ljava/util/Comparator;
```

Also notice that this would print true:

```
Comparator<Person> comp = myComparisonProvider::compareByName;
System.out.println(comp instanceof Comparator); // true
```

You can enable a flag : `-Djdk.internal.lambda.dumpProxyClasses=/Your/Path/Here`

and look at what that method reference is transformed into:

```
final class Test$$Lambda$1 implements java.util.Comparator
```

and inside it there's the `compare` method implementation(I've simplified it and removed some of it's code to make it a little more obvious):

```
public int compare(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
Code:
     4: aload_1
     5: checkcast // class Test3$Person
     8: aload_2
     9: checkcast // class Test$Person
    12: invokevirtual Test$ComparisonProvider.compareByName:(Test$Person;Test$Person;)I
```

Answer (score 1):

> Java 8 allows us to use instances of classes as if they were implementing a particular interface, while actually they are not

Not exactly, it allows you to use a single method of some instance of a class as if it were implementing some functional interface.

And it doesn't add any functionality that didn't exist in Java 7 - it just gives you a short cut to writing that functionality.

For example, instead of:

```
Arrays.sort(someArray, someInstance::someMethod);
```

In Java 7 you could use anonymous class instance to write:

```
Arrays.sort(someArray, new Comparator<SomeType> () {
                public int compare (SomeType one, SomeTypeTwo) {
                    return someInstance.someMethod(one,two);
                }
            });
```

As long as the instance method is accessible (i.e. public), you can use it as you see fit.

Comment: Seems a little odd to say it doesn't add any functionality that didn't exist in Java 7 given that Java 7 has neither method references nor the type inference that makes method references usable in place of functional interface implementations. In Java 7 you _must_ provide an instance of the explicitly typed class.

Comment: Sorry, but I can not agree completely. Note that in Java 7 style you explicitly CREATE an (instance of a class implementing) Comparator<SomeType> - so it is wordy, but it is OK. In java 8 though, you say that you expect a Comparator but provide an instance of some other class that does not have anything to do with a comparator

Comment: @pvg Perhaps that was bad phrasing on my part. I meant that using an arbitrary instance method as an implementation of some interface its class doesn't implement can still be done without method references in Java 7.

Comment: @Eran Right but the question is fundamentally about how Java 8 changes type-enforcement rules and whether that actually breaks type safety. It seems to me the answer ought to address that directly to be, well, an answer.

Comment: @Alex Mi: you do *not* “provide an instance of some other class”, you provide a *method reference*. Whether that method reference captures an instance of some class or points to a `static` method, is irrelevant.

Comment: @Holger this method reference exists in an instance of some object. It is not a "standalone" method reference, because it could change the state of the object, in which it exists. And  it is the type (the class) of this object, I am talking about. If it were a defualt method in an interafce, then it would have been a "standalone" method reference, because an interface does not have a state that can be changed.

Comment: @Alex Mi: this method reference does *not* exist “in” an instance of some object. This method reference *has* an instance. But whether it has an instance or not, is not relevant to whoever invokes the method. That’s not different to the anonymous `Comparator` example in this answer, whether it has a reference to `someInstance` is not relevant to whoever calls `Comparator.compare`. This has nothing to do with `default` methods of interfaces, this is an *implementation* of the interface and implementations may have arbitrary state.

Answer (score 1):

`Comparator` is a **functional interface**, which means that when requested you can pass an instance of a class implementing it, use a lambda expression that conforms to the type of single abstract method declared in it or use a method reference that also conforms to.

Java 8 **Functional interface** makes the difference. This tries to catch the concept of function. Afterall what is important in `Comparator` is not the type itself but the method (and its type) that should be provided at runtime. In pre Java 8 you need to provide a function object, while in Java 8 you can simply provide the function (just what is needed).

So for the type system everything is correct, provided that the lambdas or references you use are of the type of the method of the functional interface.